# Ansibleで接続時に自動で対話インストールを実行するホストに接続するには

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

Ansibleから、接続時に自動で対話インストールを実行するホストに
正常に接続するにはどうしたらいいですか？

接続を試みると、デバッグモードでは正常に対話スクリプトの出力が表示されますが、
その状態でコマンドを入力できないせいか、処理が止まってタイムアウトします。
-bオプションのときのエラーメッセージ：

> ERROR! Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt

コマンド(nmtui)が自動実行されているので、これを無効にする方法でも良いとは思いますが、無効にする方法がわかりません。
(~/.ssh/rc and /etc/ssh/sshrcは見ました)

> Aug 20 14:02:30 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal sudo[1240]: anon : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/anon ; USER=root ; COMMAND=nmtui

Ansibleのコマンド

> ansible test -m ping --private-key test.pem -vvvv

Ansible.logの抜粋

> 2018-08-19 14:31:19,003 p=3924 u=ec2-user | 3930 1534689079.00384: _low_level_execute_command() done: rc=0, stdout=, stderr=open terminal failed: not a terminal
>
> 2018-08-19 14:31:19,004 p=3924 u=ec2-user | 3930 1534689079.00403: _low_level_execute_command(): starting
>
> 2018-08-19 14:31:19,004 p=3924 u=ec2-user | 3930 1534689079.00418: _low_level_execute_command(): executing: /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/anon/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1534689078.9-277629226991869/expect.py; rm -rf "/home/anon/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1534689078.9-277629226991869/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
>
> 2018-08-19 14:31:19,029 p=3924 u=ec2-user | 3930 1534689079.02952: stdout chunk (state=2): HERE IS TUI.
>
> 2018-08-19 14:31:54,887 p=3924 u=ec2-user | 3924 1534689114.88690: RUNNING CLEANUP 2018-08-19 14:31:54,888 p=3924 u=ec2-user | [ERROR]: User interrupted execution

Comment: tui/guiではなくcui(shell)上の対話ならexpectコマンドがあれば出来るので、そちらで対応するなどの代案はいかがでしょうか？

Comment: モジュール如何でなく、そもそも正常な接続と認識されない状態です。

Answer (score 1):

例えば、PC1(centOS)からPC2(centOS)へsshログインによってAnsibleを実行する場合、特に複雑な設定はいらなかったと思います。

１、Ansibleフォルダ構成例

```
AnsibleRootフォルダ
    private_keys
        private_key_xxx
    hosts
        dev.txt
    templates
        selinux_config
    main.yml
```

２、hosts/dev.txt

```
[dev]
192.168.X.XXX:22
```

３、main.yml　の例

```
- name: install middlewares
  hosts: dev
  tasks:

  - name: disable selinux
    become: yes
    shell: bash setenforce 0
    ignore_errors: true
  - name: set selinux/config
    become: yes
    template:
      src: templates/selinux_config
      dest: /etc/selinux/config
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 644
```

４、templetes/selinux_config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

5、実際にPC1でやる事
（ログイン中のユーザー名はvagrantでsudo可能という前提）
（自分で作成したansibleフォルダは/home/vagrant/vagrant_shared/ansibleに配置されたという前提）

```
# sudo yum install epel-release
# sudo yum install ansible
# sudo yum install openssh-clients
cd /home/vagrant/vagrant_shared/ansible
cp private_keys/private_key ../../
sudo chmod 0600 ../../private_key
ansible-playbook -i hosts/dev.txt main.yml -u vagrant --private-key="../../private_key"
```